# ARG value is not expanding in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, arguments, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile with the following content

```
FROM java:v1

MAINTAINER Nitanka Gogoi <nitankagogoi@gmail.com>

ENV SPARK_URL "http://d3kbcqa49mib13.cloudfront.net/spark-2.0.2-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz"

RUN apt-get update && \

    apt-get install -y curl && \
    cd /tmp && \
    curl -o ${SPARK_URL}
```

On executing `docker build -t sparkbase:v2 .`

I am getting the following error towards the end of the log.

```
Preparing to unpack .../curl_7.35.0-1ubuntu2.10_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking curl (7.35.0-1ubuntu2.10) ...
Setting up libcurl3:amd64 (7.35.0-1ubuntu2.10) ...
Setting up curl (7.35.0-1ubuntu2.10) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.9) ...
curl: no URL specified!
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update &&     apt-get install -y curl &&    cd /tmp &&     curl -o ${SPARK_URL}' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

Can anybody help me how to have the value of SPARK_URL expanded without using `build-arg`

Comment: Your `curl` command syntax is wrong: `-o` needs the output file name, so it swallows the value of `$SPARK_URL`.

Comment: Thank you, I got the error. it should be `-O`. Thank you for your time.